# Could I use both CSS pseudo-elements on a selector: before and after for this example?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to create a horizontal menu navigation that would look like this:

{image1} ITEM1 [separator1]   {image2} ITEM2 [separator2]  etc.

I have a limitation: the HTML should be intact, unchanged. Is this possible only with CSS with the following markup: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrt4V/

For now, I tried many variations, ended up with the :before and :after pseudo-elements, but now the menu shows up like this:

{image1}  [separator1] ITEM1   {image2}  [separator2] ITEM2  etc.

I think this could be a bottleneck:

```
li a:after {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  zoom: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('http://static-caselogic-com.r.worldssl.net/images/CaseLogic/Misc/CategoryMenuSeparator.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) They're pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes 2) Bottleneck in what sense?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Bottleneck in sense I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve this by CSS only. I think I should add a SPAN, or a DIV element in between those menu items. It would be very helpful if I shouldn't change the HTML in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set the :after `display:inline-block` and remove `float:left`

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/Mrt4V/1/

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, positioning is the key part.

Added `position:relative` to `<a>` tag and `position:absolute` to the `:before` & `: after`.

The reason is to place `:before` & `:after` relative to the `<a>` tag.

I brushed up the changes in CSS to get the described result.

Below is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/gwxndwka/